# Unable to connect to URL within docker container (tomcat) - Socket exception is thrown

Tags: docker

I am facing problem within my docker container's tomcat where it is throwing socket exception while connecting to URL. Same is working fine until few days back. Same is url is getting connected from host server of docker service.

```
[localhost-startStop-1]  Error getting Properties from Config URL :http://config.server.com/config/ 
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://config.server.com/config/public/rest-less-api/query-configurations": Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:666) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
```

Unfortunately, our base docker image(organization level) doesn't include ping or ssh tools. I am bit clueless to troubleshoot the same.

```
[root@mylin# docker info
Containers: 1
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 2
Server Version: 1.13.1
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: journald
Cgroup Driver: systemd
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Authorization: rhel-push-plugin
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: docker-runc runc
Default Runtime: docker-runc
Init Binary: /usr/libexec/docker/docker-init-current
containerd version:  (expected: aa8187dbd3b7ad67d8e5e3a15115d3eef43a7ed1)
runc version: 5eda6f6fd0c2884c2c8e78a6e7119e8d0ecedb77 (expected: 9df8b306d01f59d3a8029be411de015b7304dd8f)
init version: fec3683b971d9c3ef73f284f176672c44b448662 (expected: 949e6facb77383876aeff8a6944dde66b3089574)
Security Options:
 seccomp
  WARNING: You're not using the default seccomp profile
  Profile: /etc/docker/seccomp.json
 selinux
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64
Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.5 (Maipo)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
Number of Docker Hooks: 3
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.638 GiB
Name: vc2crtp1287181n.fmr.com
ID: B4VP:4BCJ:476O:RUWA:IT3G:O7NO:DZOQ:RR6Z:QMBG:FPB5:DMSE:G5HG
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://registry.access.redhat.com/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Registries: registry.access.redhat.com (secure), docker.io (secure)
```

Edited: 
I did a few more analysis to find the same docker image works with another host server. When I ran curl command inside the docker container in the server where I had problem, I getting following error message

```
sh-4.2# curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"search-query" :"q21321", "structure-format":"FLA                                        T"}' http://config.server.com/config/public/rest-less-api/query-configurations

curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

where in another host server where image is working fine, curl command returns the values.
Any direction to resolve this problem will be of great help?

Additional Info:
Below are inspect information of the working container

```
docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "4b8207ce56b3741b7bd864f7adffdc324ba2e9db9e07ae031e10c90f351be158",
        "Created": "2018-12-06T04:29:23.258033812-05:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Containers": {
            "6bcf920c0dc86d60dd288fd086f4d971aee217cf2ee49d71fd47dc1570460504": {
                "Name": "GRK-BRK-EVENT",
                "EndpointID": "b875dcdf4db8832fe518620801ae87137c6df44697ae7035148921f6a179b64a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "de1dc8c4a9e09b2612d2d4e0ede5b875b42c4a819f27fe32ed9728d3cc4d756b": {
                "Name": "GRK-BRK-REST",
                "EndpointID": "d0149fb42645e63c0d8e9c8ad1c605f9ddcb3afa4c41e52c10a554cd31452727",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

and below is inspect log for not-working container

```
linux-x86-64]# docker inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "c245b3b5c4cedca3b9fa5370b464e0e9c2aef0dc2c520daeedf3e726e8b153e4",
        "Created": "2018-12-18T11:14:10.806753755-05:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Containers": {
            "e5bfa7fefa002b50f7e763ea30e2e602b4b577b1b558000725453773a4f10903": {
                "Name": "GRK-BRK-REST",
                "EndpointID": "64ff097ad0c72e107845c00aac2708ced6c9e896f37c317a247be7d3f482fcc0",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

I found find only difference is Gateway is added to IPAM segment in container which is not working

Comment: have you opened the port for the container when starting it

Comment: I am able to communicate to my docker container. Within my docker container i.e,tomcat apps when try to external URL's were getting socket exception. I am facing same problem when I curl command within docker container

Comment: Unable to find the root cause for the problem but found alternate to keep the things going by adding HTTP proxy in JVM args for tomcat in docker container run command